# Laravel Route::current() returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to use the current route in middleware in Laravel 5.7 using the following line of code:

```
$route = Route::current();
```

But I get a null value for `$route`. Any ideas?

Comment: But in your middleware's method you are given the request and next closure...

Comment: @ka_lin Ok then, how should I do it? I'm a little new to Middlewares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to change where your middleware is registered in `app/Http/Kernel.php` if you need access to the Route facade.

I'm betting that your middleware is in the `protected $middleware` array. It should be in one of your `$middlewareGroups` usually `web` or `api`. Or if you need it for a specific route you can add it to the `$routeMiddleware` array.

For example, I wanted to access `Route` from within my `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware so I had to move to `$middlewareGroups` like shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The route couldn't be available yet because the router hasn't been yet called. That's depends on what middlewares are called before your middleware.

I think that, in a before middleware, you can try with: `$route = $request->path();` just to be sure and not depending on the Router being booted or not.

Comment: The thing is this worked before I migrated from Laravel 5.1 to 5.7. What could have changed?

Comment: Probably has changed the point, in the chain of middlewares, in wich the Router is bootstrapped.